# Aiohttp: `async with session.get(...)` block blocks until receiving the request: why?

Tags: python, aiohttp

I have following code snipped:

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio

async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get("https://hub.dummyapis.com/delay?seconds=1") as r:
            print("Here!")
            text = await r.text()
            print(text)

asyncio.run(main())
```

The url I'm calling simply waits for one second, and then returns a `200`.

I thought the `Here!`, would be printed immediately, then 1 second would pass (or maybe a tiny bit more, including the overhead to send and receive the request), and then the text will be printed. After all, I'm only `await`ing after the `print("Here!")` statement. But that's not the case, the `Here!` is only printed after 1 second. So i guess that the `async with session.get(...) as r` is blocking? My questions:

1. What's going on here? Is it an implementation detail of `aiohttp` to wait for the response to be received, or am I misunderstanding `async` here? Can I make the `session.get(...) as r` unblocking?
2. More specifically, I would like to be able to:

- First send the request, saving a Future/awaitable (or something else?) that will resolve to a response for later.
- Do some work - which uses that Future/awaitable (specifically I would like to inspect the state of the request when it's in-flight)
- wait for the response to come through, and return

Is that possible with `aiohttp`?

Comment: It's likely that the async is working fine but output from the print call is not getting flushed to stdout immediately. Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55081531/202168

Comment: Nope that's not it, I tried it with `flush=True`, same behaviour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically it is an internal implementation. Lets investigate aiohttp implementation and start with following line of the code

```
async with session.get("https://hub.dummyapis.com/delay?seconds=1") as r:
```

Get method of `ClientSession` returns a context manager called `_RequestContextManager` [here](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/blob/4639b36852f3b4939e61311d7863f1d7450d500d/aiohttp/client.py#L931C5-L937C10). If you check this context manager, it is inherited from another context manager called [`_BaseRequestContextManager`.](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/blob/4639b36852f3b4939e61311d7863f1d7450d500d/aiohttp/client.py#L1101) In the `__aenter__` of this context manager, it basically awaits the response of request and returns response. So basically with this line, you already did request to server and it waited for 1 seconds to get response. So it is normal that "Here!" is printed after 1 seconds because the code inside the context manager is executed after response is obtained. If you check, [`text`](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/blob/edd49b5c445b1b325e483a70bdf2635d6b72f64f/aiohttp/client_reqrep.py#L1023) method of `ClientResponse`, you can see that this methods only gets body of response and decodes it.

Answer (score 1):

Because it needs to wait to read the headers, and your URL is waiting 1 second to send anything, not just the body. And the body is just `This response has been delayed for 1 seconds`, so you won't notice any delay between `print("Here!")` and `print(text)`.

If you request from an URL that only delays the body, you will notice that getting "Here" takes minimal time.

```
import aiohttp, asyncio, time

async def test(url):
    start = time.monotonic()
    print(url)
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        print(f"[{time.monotonic() - start:6.3f}] Session")
        async with session.get(url) as r:
            print(f"[{time.monotonic() - start:6.3f}] Here")
            text = await r.text()
            print(f"[{time.monotonic() - start:6.3f}] Body: {text!r}")
    print()


async def main():
    await test("https://hub.dummyapis.com/delay?seconds=10")
    await test("https://httpbin.org/drip?duration=10&delay=0")

asyncio.run(main())
```

This prints out:

```
https://hub.dummyapis.com/delay?seconds=10
[ 0.000] Session
[10.203] Here
[10.203] Body: 'This response has been delayed for 10 seconds'

https://httpbin.org/drip?duration=10&delay=0
[ 0.000] Session
[ 0.469] Here
[ 9.672] Body: '**********'
```